# One button, two different actions asp.net core mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net

So the idea is when I click on the button -

```
<a asp-controller="#" asp-action="#" asp-route-id="#">Add to Watchlist</a>
```

the movie needs to be added to a watchlist and the behaviour of the button changed to "Remove from watchlist" and to point different action and controller that has the logic to remove the movie from the watchlist. Is that possible?

Comment: Why not render both buttons on your view and show/hide the appropriate button dependent on what the user clicked and the initial status of the "movie"?

Comment: are you trying to avoid having a handler/method that otherwise makes that determination? provider a view and controller sample please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is to have both buttons there and one of them to be hidden

```
<a asp-controller="#" asp-action="#" asp-route-id="#" id="addToWatchlist">Add to Watchlist</a>
<a asp-controller="#" asp-action="#" asp-route-id="#" id="removeFromWatchlist" style="display: none">Remove from Watchlist</a>
```

Then you can use JavaScript to show/hide the buttons when they're clicked.

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('addToWatchlist').onclick = function () {
        document.getElementById('removeFromWatchlist').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('addToWatchlist').style.display = "none";
    }
    document.getElementById('removeFromWatchlist').onclick = function () {
    }
    document.getElementById('removeFromWatchlist').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('addToWatchlist').style.display = "block";
</script>
```

Comment: There is another problem - When i click on Add to watchlist button, the movie is added to the users watchlist, but what should return as a View ? The value of button is still the same "Add to watchlist "

Comment: @ItsoDimitrov Well, you can have a bool property inside your Movie class and based on it you can load the correct button on the View. e.g. bool AddedToWatchlist = false. Whenever the button Add to Watchlist is clicked you can update the bool and afterwards based on it to show/hide the correct button using Razor in MVC instead of JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

there are [different ways to do it and in this tutorial](http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/2678a2f2-3236-45a6-a0e5-e6340d9930d5.aspx) you can find different ways

Or maybe you can try to use razor to add a conditional expression to define the asp-action depending on a variable somethink like asp-action="@Model.wasAddedToWatchList ? RemoveAction:AddAction"